# Twitter OAuth Access Token Error: Request token missing

Tags: laravel, twitter, postman, twitter-oauth, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to run through a proof of concept social sign in flow with Twitter using Postman, following this guide: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/implementing-sign-in-with-twitter

I'm stuck on step 3: Converting the request token to an access token

I'm using Postman's built in Authorization for OAuth 1.0 and have provided values for my Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token, and Token Secret.

No matter what I try, the response from my `POST` to `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token` is a `401`:

```
Request token missing
```

I'm including my `oauth_verifier` from step 2 as `x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

My project is being developed with Laravel and Socialite. I've also tried using the `getTokenCredentials` method on the `League\OAuth1\Client\Server\Server` class and get the same `Request token missing` error.

My end goal is to use the `userFromTokenAndSecret` method provided by the Twitter Socialite driver to retrieve user profile data.

Has anyone encountered this error before?

Comment: are you sure you are sending in the correct token? 

for `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token`, you have to use the token obtained from step 2. 

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth
`https://yourWhitelistedCallbackUrl.com?oauth_token=NPcudxy0yU5T3tBzho7iCotZ3cnetKwcTIRlX0iwRl0&oauth_verifier=uw7NjWHT6OJ1MpJOXsHfNxoAhPKpgI8BlYDhxEjIBY`

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't realize the token would change per step. Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue but... in the example linked above, the request token remains the same at all steps? (it is oauth_token=NPcudxy0yU5T3tBzho7iCotZ3cnetKwcTIRlX0iwRl0 in step 2 and 3). Completely lost...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't realize the token would also change per step. After using the correct tokens, I'm able to authenticate successfully with Twitter.

Answer (score 6):

For users like me and @seinecle who were facing the issue despite having the right token, the Twitter's Postman collection has an issue. Simply change step-3's Authorization type to "No Auth" and send the request again.

EDIT: Link to postman collection -  https://www.postman.com/twitter/workspace/twitter-s-public-workspace/collection/241622-2f1af03a-a3fe-4b8a-9b1a-bd0b84789e50

Comment: This is correct answer if you are using the Twitter OAuth 1.0a flow test postman collection.

Comment: I am using the Twitter OAuth 1.0a postman collection and this is what I needed, thanks!

Comment: can you please tell me what is oauth_verifier and how can i get it from step-2?

Comment: `oauth_verifier` is passed as a query parameter in the request that Twitter sends to your callback url. @cagri